# Easy to follow redux core using rxjs that support middleware?

Tags: node.js, redux, rxjs

My team is currently maintaining a **stateful** **node** server that uses [**rxjs**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs). We would like to use a **Redux** middleware([redux-auto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-auto)) in this project to clean up the logic. I have found in several places that you can use **rxjs** to achieve the same result as Redux.

So we don't want to install another dependency i.e Redux if we already have Rxjs installed that can do the same job.

However the example implementations of [redux implemented using rxjs](https://hackernoon.com/diy-redux-with-rxjs-rxdx-23163a87ade1) all seem to address only using [one reducer](http://rudiyardley.com/redux-single-line-of-code-rxjs/) and we would like to use a [middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-auto). We found [rxdx](https://github.com/onerzafer/rxdx) but its a little hard to follow, would be better to have a condensed version that fits in one file.

So my question is can someone share or point me to a small rxjs example with support for adding redux middlewares?

FROM: http://rudiyardley.com/redux-single-line-of-code-rxjs/

```
const Subject = Rx.Subject;

// create our stream as a subject so arbitrary data can be sent on the stream
const action$ = new Subject();

// Initial State
const initState = { name: 'Harry' };

// Redux reducer
const reducer = (state, action) => {  
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'NAME_CHANGED':
      return {
        ...state,
        name: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

// Reduxification
const store$ = action$  
    .startWith(initState)
    .scan(reducer);

// Higher order function to send actions to the stream
const actionDispatcher = (func) => (...args) =>  
  action$.next(func(...args));

// Example action function
const changeName = actionDispatcher((payload) => ({  
  type: 'NAME_CHANGED',
  payload
}));


store$.subscribe((state) => console.log(state));
changeName('Ben')
changeName('Sally')
```

I was trying..

```js
const customMiddleWare = store => next => action => {
  console.log("Current state:",store.getState());
  console.log("Middleware triggered:", action);
  next(action);
}

store$.subscribe((state) => lastState = state);
let lastState = initState;
const store = { 
  getState: () => lastState, 
  dispatch: action$.next
}

customMiddleWare(store)
```

But I can't workout how to wire it into the **rx store**? What should `next` & `action` be in the context of the middleware?

Thanks for your help on this

Comment: In [rxdx](https://github.com/onerzafer/rxdx) they seem to have what you are looking for [effectsMiddleware.js](https://github.com/onerzafer/rxdx/blob/master/src/effectsMiddleware.js)

Comment: If you still want to use redux middleware, why not try out [redux-observable](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable) for action dispatching, redux and implement `store.getState$` read side with rxjs?

Comment: I want to use a middleware we like but I don't want to install another dependency i.e Redux if we already have Rxjs installed that can do the same job.

Comment: I won't use redux at all

Comment: Is redux-auto the only middleware you want to depend on (without using redux)? You seem to be the author, so it would be reasonable to divide the library in a common and a redux specific connector component. Other middlewares are more or less a thin adapter layer around redux in order to use callbacks/promises/generators/observables for dispatching.

Answer (score -1):

This is an opinionated answer to your question rather than a solution, but it is the best thing to do nonethless.

Use Redux.

It is tiny, and is dependent on only 3 other libraries (and that's the entire dependency tree.) In addition you have its ecosystem (which includes the middleware you want and plenty of documentation on using it) and the advantage that developers have a chance of already knowing Redux (even with RxJS - it's what we do!) but no chance of knowing your in-house solution which will save **so much** 'education' time for new hires.

In short the amount of effort you will have to expend to reduce your code size by mere kilobytes really isn't worth it.

Comment: Hi @Abulafia. Thank you for your contribution. I understand your point and there is value in what you say. However I would still like this specific coding problem solved for completeness within the Rxjs Space. Someone else down the line may wish to combine streams + stateful + middleware within their own pattern.

Comment: I'm not saying the pattern is bad; just trying to get it work with current Redux middleware.
The point the author is making in that article is that the pattern can be implemented in RxJS, not that it is a pluggable replacement.
If you are determined to follow this path, you would need to wrap your Redux middleware in an interfacing function that would convert dispatches to a mergeMap of new actions into your stream, but it will probably have so many edge cases that you will essentially need a different wrapper for each middleware.This will just be more complicated than it will ever be worth.